# How to set touch event for TableRow

Tags: android

I have added many cells into table row unfortunately, the table row cannot receive click event even thought I have also create the onClickListener for this table row. Here is my code block.

```
row = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.row);

    monday = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.monday);

    monday.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "monday click", 1000).show();
        }
    });

    row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "row click", 2000).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: You may want to use `View.OnTouchListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:clickable="true"` in tablerow tag in your xml file

Comment: I cannot get "row click" message after added above tag into my xml file, just only "monday click" message.

Comment: try  row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() instead of  row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

Comment: Please clean your project and test.